# Enterprise Quicksight on multiple regions on same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

We have a work aws account that houses different data sets based in different regions.
We have also have Quicksight Enterprise, with the default region being southeast Sydney.

While working in the Sydney region all Enterprise level tools work as they should, however,
when I switch regions to work on the us-west N Viriginia region, no Enterprise level features, such as SPICE and alerting are available.

Is there a way to have enterprise level features across multiple regions since it is on the same account?

Tried going through Manage Quicksight options on the console, but no options are available unless changing region back to Sydney which has all the Enterprise level stuff enabled already.

Solution would ideally not involve having to pay for another Enterprise instance to be set up and payed for.

Thanks